# Charge a 200v capacitor to 200V with a 5V Power Supply

Tags: capacitor, dc

If for example I have a 200VDC capacitor and I need to fully charge it to 200VDC. Can I do so with a 5VDC power supply and if I can how would I do this?

Comment: um.. What is yes for 100 Alex?

Comment: Disassemble a camera flash? Most camera flashes charges a capacitor to 300V with 4AAs (4.8V to 6V depending on battery type and condition).

Comment: @user3528438 Disposable cameras charge caps to ~300V with a single AA or AAA battery (1.5V)

Comment: Google for "electronic flash circuit".  You asked if there was a way to do it without a transformer.  Yes, Google for "voltage multiplier," but going from 5V to 200V without magnetics will be somewhat of an engineering challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is:

1. Use the 5 VDC power supply to build an oscillator.
2. Step up the resultant AC voltage using a 400:5 transformer.
3. Rectify the resultant output.

You'll now have a 200 VDC supply, which is capable of providing a lot less current than your original power supply. Thus, you can charge your capacitor to 200 VDC. I think this must be a standard way of stepping up DC voltages and must have a standard name. If any reader knows this name, please put it in a comment.

Comment: Would there be a way of doing this in a small circuit without a transformer?

Comment: @Matt121 If you don't want to use a transformer you can build a boost converter that uses an inductor to store the magnetic field and release it at a high voltage. Google "boost converter".

Comment: "Invertor" comes to mind. @Matt121 since you now have a lethal voltage, not using a transformer could be detrimental to your and your circuits health on the 5V side.

Comment: 200V is the max voltage... go there with caution.

Comment: @Matt121 if your poking around in there you are at risk of death.. If the 5V comes from say your PC USB port, and there is a fault in the circuit, you could blow up your PCB.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks, that helps to clarify things. I will most likely power it using battery's and a voltage regulator, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: You really don't need a DC supply. The capacitor could be charged using pulses.

Answer (score 1):

Charge up 40 Caps to 5V with the supply while they are all in parallel with the supply, then disconnect them and put them in series. The voltages will add and 5V*40 = 200V